Fit table cell to the div inside it with flexbox
I created a "schedule calendar" on my webpage, which should display existing appointments according to the data provided in the Model from the back-end side:
<table class="calendar">
    <thead>
        <tr class="calendar-row">
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
            <th>Sun</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Generate calendar grid -->
        <tr th:each="week : ${calendar}" class="calendar-row">
            <th:block th:each="day : ${week}">
                <td th:if="${day}"  class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number" th:text="${day.getDayOfMonth()}"></span>
                    <div class="appointment" th:each="appointment : ${appointments}"
                         th:if="${appointment.date.toLocalDate().isEqual(day.toLocalDate())}"
                         th:text="|${appointment.date.toLocalTime().toString()} - ${appointment.title}|">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td th:unless="${day}" class="empty-day-cell"></td>
            </th:block>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

stylesheet:
.calendar {
    border-collapse: separate;
}

.calendar th, .calendar td {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.calendar-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.empty-day-cell {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 80px;
    min-height: 80px;
}

.day-cell {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 80px;
    min-height: 80px;
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.day-number {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.appointment {
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 0 10%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    background: teal;
    padding: 0 10%;
}

and the result looks like this (pasting an image, not a jsfiddle link, because of all the Thymeleaf tags that won't work good without backend data):
EDIT: also link: https://jsfiddle.net/zax3fq7c/

Unfortunately the cells does not seem to help me with resizing themselves to fit to the "appointments" size...
Most probably I messed up with flexboxes, although I believed that I understand the concept when creating this layout. Here few questions arise:

How to make the cells resize themselves so the tasks are contained in a single cell, not overlay like on the image?
How can I make several appointments like shown on 22th have the same box size as the longest one?
(cosmetic and not very important one) 1st and 2nd boxes are slightly wider than the ones in the following rows, I can't find the reason behind this, can someone explain this to me? I guess it has to do with having no border in "empty-day-cell", but giving it 1px transparent border doesn't change anything actually.


Have you tried using display: grid instead of flex. it seems what you want is a more frigid column column structure.

@K i: Yes, I tried, but changing display of the .day-cell alone doesn't do much in this case. I guess it's somehow made difficult by the upper-level styles, but I can't identify the core of the problem.

Can you make a reproducable demo of the code to make it earier to inspect the styles?

@K i: For a brief moment I forgot there is a generated final code accessible in the browser ;)
https://jsfiddle.net/zax3fq7c/

You are on the right track. I made some adjustments to your styles... below.
I used overflow hidden in conjunction with flex to hide/show overflowing content. (Bonus for truncation added in there too ;-)
I replaced most of your min-width and min-height rules with "auto" and "100%" to make those appointment boxes the full width of their containers.
Last, you need to reset left/right padding on the first row's cells and specify "border: 1px solid transparent" or remove borders altogether.


.calendar {
    font-family: 'Arial', helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
}

.calendar th, .calendar td {
    min-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.calendar-row:first-child > td.day-cell {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.calendar-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: stretch;
}

.calendar-row th {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.empty-day-cell, .day-cell {
    border: 1px solid transparent !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0.1rem;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

.day-cell {
    background: #eeeeeecc;
    padding: 1.5rem 0.25rem 0 0.25rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

.day-number {
    background: #ffffffcc;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.1rem 0.2rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.appointment {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    background: #ccb9ffcc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
    padding: 0.1rem 0.5rem;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.day-cell:has(.appointment):hover {
    background-color: #e1daf0cc;
    overflow: unset !important;
    flex-grow: 1 !important;
    padding: 1.5rem 0.75rem 0 0.75rem;
}

.day-cell:has(.appointment):hover > div {
    display: block;
    -webkit-line-clamp: unset;
    -webkit-box-orient: unset;
    overflow: unset !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
<table class="calendar">
    <thead>
        <tr class="calendar-row">
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
            <th>Sun</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Generate calendar grid -->
        <tr class="calendar-row">
            
                
                <td class="empty-day-cell"></td>
            
                
                <td class="empty-day-cell"></td>
            
                
                <td class="empty-day-cell"></td>
            
                
                <td class="empty-day-cell"></td>
            
                
                <td class="empty-day-cell"></td>
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">1</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">2</span>
                </td>
                
            
        </tr>
        <tr class="calendar-row">
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">3</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">4</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">5</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">6</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">7</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">8</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">9</span>
                </td>
                
            
        </tr>
        <tr class="calendar-row">
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">10</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">11</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">12</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">13</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">14</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">15</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">16</span>
                </td>
                
            
        </tr>
        <tr class="calendar-row">
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">17</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">18</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">19</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">20</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">21</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">22</span>
                        <div class="appointment">14:15 - Some Job</div>
                        <div class="appointment">16:15 - Other Task</div>
                        <div class="appointment">18:15 - Even Longer Task</div>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">23</span>
                </td>
                
            
        </tr>
        <tr class="calendar-row">
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">24</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">25</span>                 
                        <div class="appointment">14:00 - Presentation</div>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">26</span>

                </td>
                
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">27</span>
                </td>
                
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">28</span>
                     <div class="appointment">10:30 - Training Location</div>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">29</span>
                </td>
                
            
                <td class="day-cell">
                    <span class="day-number">30</span>
                </td>
       
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



